# Making a custom template for CreateView and UpdateView with placeholders and error validation

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-generic-views

I'm making a generic blog while learning Django.

I have an `ArticleCreateView` and `ArticleUpdateView`, and I am trying to make a custom template that both views would share.
From what I understand, `CreateView` and `UpdateView` use the same template by default (`article_form.html`), which is the template I'm trying to modify.

I have the following in my models.py:

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    body = models.TextField()
    # def __str__ ...
    # def get_absolute_url ...
```

In my views.py:

```py
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ['title', 'body']      
    template_name = 'article_form.html'


class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Article
    fields = ['title', 'body']
    template_name = 'article_form.html'
```

Having the following in my template article_form.html works:

```html
<form method='post'>
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button>
    Publish
  </button>
</form>
```

I want to make it more fancy though, with loads of CSS, and a simplified version is:

```html
<form method='post'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <fieldset class="fieldset-class">
    {{ form.title.errors }}
    <input
      class="form-class"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Article Title"
      name="{{ form.title.name }}"
      value="{{ form.title.value }}"
    />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    {{ form.body.errors }}
    <textarea
      class="form-control"
      rows="8"
      placeholder="Article Body"
      name="{{ form.body.name }}"
    >{{ form.body.value }}</textarea>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

What I want is a form that:

- has placeholders in empty fields (instead of labels)
- has model-based error validation (`max_length` is respected and both fields are `required` without me having to specify it)
- doesn't erase the entered values upon submitting

The above html does the following:

- submitting with empty fields will raise the errors, and any entered values will be persisted (good)
- empty fields have `None` instead of placeholders (issue)

Substituting `object.title` and `object.body` to `form.title.value` and `form.body.value` in the above html does the following:

- submitting with empty fields will raise the errors, but also erase the entered values (issue)
- empty fields have the right placeholders (good)

I have read the documentation's [Built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-template-tags-and-filters), [Rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually), [Rendering form error messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages), [Looping over the form’s fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields), and [Attributes of BoundField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#attributes-of-boundfield), looked for similar code on SO and GitHub, read the source rendered by `{{ form.as_p }}`, but I find no simple solution despite having a supposedly common usecase.

The only thing I can think of is to shove `{% if %}` statements everywhere to choose between `placeholder` and `value`, or to get some third-party lib like [crispy-forms](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/), but it feels like a more pythonic solution should exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, I found the answer immediately after posting the question on SO.

The built-in template filter `default_if_none` solves the issue:

```py
    <input
      class="form-class"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Article Title"
      name="{{ form.title.name }}"
      value="{{ form.title.value|default_if_none:'' }}"
    />
```

Comment: I can only accept my answer in 2 days, but consider the question solved.